# Xcode error "Framework not found ARCoreBase.xcframework"

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine, cocoapods, arcore

I'm a Japanese student.
I'm making an AR application using Google ARCore Geospatial API in Unity.
I have imported and configured the necessary packages such as AR Extensions and am trying to test it on an actual device.

I can build it on Unity without error, but when I build it on iPad, I get the following error on Xcode.

```
・Framework not found ARCoreBase.xcframework
・linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Development environment
・Unity 2021.3.27f1
・Xcode：Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)
・Mac mini(M2Pro) OS：Ventura 13.4.1

Please advise.

I have tried installing pods, opening in .xcworkspace, updating Unity packages, etc., but no solution.
There is no mention of ARCore/Base in the profile, so that may be the cause.

The contents of the profile are as follows.

> source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
>
> platform: ios, '12.0'
>
> target 'UnityFramework' do   pod 'ARCore/GARSession', '~> 1.37.0'
> pod 'ARCore/Geospatial', '~> 1.37.0' end target 'Unity-iPhone' do end
> use_frameworks! :linkage => :static